# Usage of 付加的な意味 in a sentence

Tags: meaning

From the dictionary it seems "付加的" means "additive".

However, in the below conversation, I can't see how it fits. It seem to be used for something else.

```
「たとえば私が余命幾許もない身であるとしたら」
「嫌な仮定がきた」
「私の書く本も、私の口にする言葉も、付加的な意味をもってとらえられることになるでしょう？」
「おそらくはそうだろうね」
```

Can someone please help me understand what this means here?

Does it mean he is thinking he will somehow be implicated in causing her death? Or that he will die himself soon? (The first line is the girl, the second is the guy).

You can see the entire context [here](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n6819cy/6/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“*Suppose* (たとえば…としたら) I was in a terminal state, with little time left (余命幾許もない身).  Then, whatever I said or wrote *would be treated* (とらえられる) as if it *held additional meaning* （付加的な意味をもって）, wouldn't it?”

She's asserting that people ascribe special/extraneous significance to the words of those near death.  That example supports her conclusion that 今のこの時代、本は作者と近すぎる—these days, books are too close to authors.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I totally misunderstood this one, and glad I double-checked!

Answer (score 2):

付加的 means “additive,” as you understand, and “additional,” “supplemental,” or “extra.”

I would translate the given quote as follows:

“Suppose my days are numbered.”

“It’s a horrible assumption.”

“My books and my words I speak would be interpreted with an extra nuance.”

“Perhaps, I think so.”

Here 付加的 means “additional or “extra” (imprecations) than the author originally intended.